# Blender glass dome without sphere mesh

Tags: mesh, objects, glass

[image]I'm trying to create a glass dome with a nine-sided base without a modified sphere mesh to create the triangle pattern. How can I correctly align different tiles to make a complete dome? (Rectangles, Triangles,...)